# UINavigationBar is not rotating

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, rotation, uinavigationbar

I am experiencing a little problem. I'm trying to develop an app with UINavigationController bar but it is not rotating although my tableView is. 
Just a little introduction so you know what my application is right now : I have a UITableView which is created in IB and linked in my class ViewController.h and a UINavigationController created in the appDelegate.h. All the items in the tableView can be clicked and it will slide to another viewController but this part is not important for now. I'm just trying to support rotation in the main view for now.

I create the UINavigationController in my AppDelegate.h like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navigation;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
```

And then in AppDelegate.m I do this :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; 
    viewController.title = @"Agrinuvo";
    [navigation pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    [_window addSubview:navigation.view];
}
```

I have tried in my ViewController.m viewDidLoad method these :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

I am able to resize the UINavigationBar but I cannot rotate it for the life of me (still in ViewController.m) :

```
-(void) orientationChanged
{
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    frame.size.height = 44;
    frame.origin.y = 15;
}
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1);
    frame.size.height = 44;
}
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5);
    frame.size.height = 32;
}
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
    frame.size.height = 32; 
}
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
}
```

Ah yes, I also tried this method in all of my controllers and it is returning YES in all of them but the NavigationBar still does not rotate.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

So I'm wondering if it is actually possible to rotate a NavigationBar. Also do I create it like it should be created?
Should I be initiating my UINavigationController this way or should I be creating it in IB and link it to a .h class?

Sorry for the long read and thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Why don't you have your navigation controller as the root view controller for your window? Making it so might fix the problem.

Comment: Wow. That actually did it... -.- Now I'm left with 1 problem the tableview doesnt rotate properly. Whould you make an answer out of your comment so I accept your answer? or should I just delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your navigation controller the root view controller of the window.  Also, in your applicationDidBecomeActive:method, you have this line: [navigation pushViewController:viewController animated:NO]; which you use before you've instantiated navigation, so that line isn't doing anything.